# Matlab: Getter runs before Constructor?

Tags: matlab

Given an object with custom get-methods for some properties, does Matlab execute some of the code (the getter) before the class constructor is executed?

Even if i set the default of a property to empty, and have a getter (!) open an io connection to a file, when I step through the debugger, even on the first line the object is already defined as file.io (with a filepath that corresponds the information available to the object before the constructor ran). How can this be, and whats the reasoning behind this implementation?

Edit: A breakpoint in the get method does not halt the debugger, so I'm not sure wether it is actually executed or not.

Edit 2: It seems like the getter is executed after the constructor is entered, after the debugger halts in the first line, before the first line is executed. No halt at breakpoint within get method though...

---

As per request, some code:

```
classdef Cat < handle
properties
    filename
    poop = [];  % my data matrix the cat is there to produce/manage
end
methods
    function obj = Cat(config)
        obj.filename = config.FILENAME; % Halt debugger in this line
    end
    function value = get.poop(obj)
        obj.poop = matfile(obj.filename)
        value = obj.poop.ingredients; % 'ingeredients' being the name of the variable in poopfile.mat
    end
end
end
```

To debug, I call

```
myCat = Cat(config)
```

from a different script. Workspace is cleared and path is rehashed.

When the debugger halts, obj.poop is not `[]`, but is already a reference to some undefined file, and the reference to the linked file obj.poop.Source is empty, which is obvious, as obj.filename has not been set yet.

Comment: Could you paste the relevant code of your class, just to be more clear on what you're asking, please?

Comment: Is your `Dependent` property getters defined as `Static`?

Comment: My property is to my knowledge neither dependent nor static (perhaps being dependent it is implied somewhere?) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for posting the code, I'll give it a run and come back with feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Test setup:**

With a slightly modified class `Cat.m`:

```
    classdef Cat < handle
            properties
                    filename
                    poop = [];
            end

            methods
                    function obj = Cat(config)
                            display('In constructor.');
                            obj.filename = config.FILENAME;
                    end

                    function value = get.poop(obj)
                            display('In poop getter.');
                            obj.poop = matfile(obj.filename);
                            value = obj.poop.ingredients;
                    end
            end
    end
```

to display the execution order of the class methods, and the `test.m` script:

```
    ingredients = 1:100;
    save('a', 'ingredients');

    config.FILENAME = 'a.mat';

    myCat = Cat(config)
```

I got the following result:

```
    >>test
    In constructor.

    myCat = 

    In poop getter.
      Cat handle

      Properties:
        filename: 'a.mat'
            poop: [1x100 double]

      Methods, Events, Superclasses
```

Please note that the first assignment in the getter method was ended with semicolon (while in the original code was not).

**In conclusion:**

1. The `get.poop()` method is called after the constructor, as expected. This was tested on MATLAB R2012a, but I strongly believe that this is not a matter of version.
2. The reason for which `get.poop()` method is called is because the assignment `myCat = Cat(config)` is not ended with a semicolon `;`.

**Rationale:**

The default behavior for assignments not ended with semicolon is to display the result of assignment. Displaying an object means, among other things, displaying the values of public properties. To get the value of the public property `poop`, `get.poop()` is called; that explains the getter call. Once the statement is changed to `myCat = Cat(config);`, the getter is not called anymore, because the result of assignment is not displayed anymore.

**Later note:**

Please note also that every request for display of the object will call the getter. So, yes, the getter might be called while the constructor is still halted by the debugger, because you inspect the `poop` member.

Comment: Haha genius, thanks for figuring it out. This makes perfect sense!

Comment: @phi Well, this kind of "quantum" getters (observing the object will change the object) are always trouble. I know this is unrequested advice and I don't want to sound patronizing, but -- if you'd ask me -- you'd be better with a "classic" getter with no side effects. That means, open the .mat file in the constructor rather than in the getter.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the advice :) It's a bit more complicated though, the matrices are too large to fit into ram, and I need to load/unload them depending on other states of my app. Furthermore, other tools access the same data provider, and directly access them. So I need to make sure that the data provides the right data when it is accessed. It's also not only matfiles that are loaded, also xls and csv files...

Comment: For those super smart people who think they know better (a.k.a me three weeks ago): Trust this man. He knows. No matter how smart you think you are, you're not.